# Equivalent of LinkedList in Java to C++ code

Tags: java, c++

I am converting the source code from JAVA (working) to C++. Although I have very little experience in C++, I have managed to convert most of the code but I can't find the equivalent of import `java.util.LinkedList;` in C++. At the moment of compiling I get an error in these lines. Does anyone have any idea how I can convert these functions?

Code in JAVA:

```
package co.unicauca.robotindustrial;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class RobotIndustrial{
    protected List<Articulacion> arts;
    protected List<Sensor> sensors;
    protected List<Movimiento> movimientos;
    
    public RobotIndustrial(){
        arts = new LinkedList<>();
        sensors = new LinkedList<>();
        movimientos = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    
    public void addArticulacion(Articulacion a){
        arts.add(a);
    }
    
    public void addSensor(Sensor s){
        sensors.add(s);
    }
    
    public void addMovimiento(Movimiento m){
        movimientos.add(m);
    }
    
    public void configurarRobot(){
         this.armarRobot();
         this.definirRecorrido();
    }
    
    public void action(){
       
        for( Movimiento each: movimientos){
            each.execute();
        }
    }    
    public abstract void definirRecorrido();
    public abstract void armarRobot();
}
```

Code in C++

```
#pragma once

#include "Articulacion.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Movimiento.h"
#include <vector>
#include <list>



    class RobotIndustrial
    {
    protected:
        std::vector<Articulacion*> arts;
        std::vector<Sensor*> sensors;
        std::vector<Movimiento*> movimientos;

    public:
        RobotIndustrial()
        {
            arts = std::list<Articulacion>();
            sensors = std::list<Sensor>();
            movimientos = std::list<Movimiento>();
        }

        virtual void addArticulacion(Articulacion *a)
        {
            arts.push_back(a);
        }

        virtual void addSensor(Sensor *s)
        {
            sensors.push_back(s);
        }
```

Comment: `I get an error in these lines` What error, what lines? Your class is not finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arts` is `std::list<Articulacion*>`, you are assigning `std::list<Articulacion>()`. The same for `sensors` and `movimientos`. You should not initialize these variables, this looks like initializing the default value with the default value.

```
RobotIndustrial()
{
  arts = std::list<Articulacion>();
  sensors = std::list<Sensor>();
  movimientos = std::list<Movimiento>();
}
```

should be

```
RobotIndustrial() = default;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer is the solution. You helped me a lot!!!